# Getting the wrong output? My coding is maybe off?

Tags: java

Well, I am doing a practice problem (preparing for midterm) and I was able to get one of the outputs correct. However, I am having troublesome getting the average input. It ends up at 12.0 instead of 6.5

Here's the prompt question:5.

> Complete the following Java program by filling in the bodies of functions sum(), avg(), and ord(). A call to sum(n) should return the sum of all the integers from 1 to n, while avg(n) returns the average of the same set of numbers. A call to the boolean function ord(x, y, z) returns true if x < y< z and false otherwise. The Function main() should produce the following output
>
> Output:
>
> 6.5  true false

This is my code:

```
class Problem5 {
    // sum(): return 1+2+3+..+n 
    static int sum(int n) {  //this is given
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            sum += n;
        }
        return n;
    }

    // avg(): return average of {1,2,..,n}
    static double avg(int n) { // given
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            sum +=n;
        }
        return sum / n;
    }

    //ord(): return true if and only if x<y<z
    static boolean ord(double x, double y, double z){ //given
        if (x < y && y <z){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args) { 
       System.out.println(avg(12));
       System.out.println(ord(1.2,3.4,5.6));
       System.out.println(ord(3.4,1.2,5.6));
    }
}
```

Overall I am having trouble coding/ filling in the code for `static int sum(int)` and `static double avg(int)`.

Comment: this does not compile, as `sum` is not declared in `avg`.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your indentation...

Comment: Fastest would be `return n*(n+1)/2`, but I think the goal is to understand coding, not maths... ;-)

Comment: as a side note, `sum([1...n]) == n*(n+1)/2`, `avg([1...n]) == (n+1)/2` (no need for loop), (That is not related to programming, but rather to math)

Comment: *"it gave me errors"* What are the errors?

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)` is not the same as `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`, the latter is actually going over all the numbers from `1` to (and inclusive) `n`. `sum += n` actually sums up `n` `n` times (i.e. `n*n`)

Comment: Why the downvotes guys. If you give downvotes, add an explanation why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++){
```

Will skip `n`. (it will loop on 1...n-1). For `12`, the sum will be `11*12/2`, which you then divide by `12`, resulting in `11/2` = 6.5

Fix it like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

(or replace the whole loop by `return (double) (n+1) / 2.0`)

For your `sum` function, there is the same error, plus the return value is not good:

```
return n;
```

Should be

```
return sum;
```

And the increment should be `sum += i;`, not `n` (you want 1+2+3+4..., not 12+12+12+12...)

Again, you can replace the whole loop by `return n * (n + 1) / 2`

I assume your teacher would expect you to learn about re usability, and since your 2 loops in `sum` and in `avg` are identical, you could write:

```
public static double avg(int n) {
    return (double) sum(n) / n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This made a lot sense to me. Thanks for pointing out my mistakes and explaining.

Answer (score 0):

A sum is just the addition of all the numbers in a certain range:

```
static int sum(int n) {
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        total += i;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Average is just the sum of the range divided by the amount of numbers:

```
static double avg(int n) {
    return sum(n) / (double) n;
}
```

Comment: the `total += 1;` loop is priceless

Comment: I'm a Python programmer, by profession, just kidding I'm in high school. But why the downvotes, the code works fine?

Comment: it works, but my eyes are bleeding (you are right, though it does not mandate a downvote. sorry about that.)

Comment: I fixed it, how are your eyes?